# Get the value assigned to a variable within a long String

Tags: java, search

I have a String that is passed from a database that is essentially an email body and contains content like bellow:

> Content-Type: application/pdf; name="mozilla.pdf" Content-Description:
>   mozilla.pdf Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mozilla.pdf";
>   size=92442; creation-date="Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT";
>   modification-date="Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00
>   GMT"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"

I want to be able to get the **filename**, **Content-Type**, etc.

For example: from the above text the **filename** will be ***mozilla.pdf***

Comment: so, they just look like name value pairs, splitting on `=` may do the job

Comment: you need to write your own parser which will parse the string into a map of key and values

Comment: Beyond that: what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no fix pattern in the input string, you have to either write your own parser or you can use different regex to fetch different parameters. For e.g. to fetch `filename`, you can use:

```
final String regex = "filename=\"(.*?)\";";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(<input-string>);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Filename: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove your `"` and `;` from the string, secondly, split them by all the terms you would like to retrieve such as `filename`, `size` etc... Then loop through the new Array and split them by `:` and `=`. Finally just put them in a `HashMap` in order to retrieve them like that, `map.get("filename")`. See the solution below.

Edit: As you asked to create a `ArrayList<String>` in order to collect all the values under the same key, I updated it as below.

Note: in order to don't split `filename` with `name`, I put `name` with a space as term.

```
String string = "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"mozilla.pdf\" name=\"mozilla2.pdf\" name=\"mozilla3.pdf\" Content-Description: mozilla.pdf Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"mozilla.pdf\"; size=92442; creation-date=\"Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT\"; modification-date=\"Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT\"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
string = string.replaceAll("[\";]", "");
String[] parts = string.split("(?=(Content-Type)|( name)|(Content-Description)|(Content-Disposition)|(filename)|(size)|(creation-date)|(modification-date)|(Content-Transfer-Encoding))");
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
for (String part : parts) {
  String[] keyValue = part.split("[:=]");
  String key = keyValue[0].trim();
  String value = keyValue[1].trim();
  ArrayList<String> list;
  if(map.containsKey(key)){
    list = map.get(key);
    list.add(value);
  } else {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(value);
    map.put(key, list);
  }
}
System.out.println(map.get("name"));
System.out.println(map.get("Content-Type"));
System.out.println(map.get("filename"));
System.out.println(map.get("creation-date"));
System.out.println(map.get("size"));
```

Output

```
[mozilla.pdf, mozilla2.pdf, mozilla3.pdf]
[application/pdf]
[mozilla.pdf]
[Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14]
[92442]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works nicely. The only issue. I am not any good with Collection. And There are instances where filename for instance appears more than once. I tries a Map that maps a key to a String[]. But that went South.

Comment: @magerine : As I really want you to learn how wonderful collections are, I changed my solution in order to collect multiple values into a list. In my example, you can now see the multiple `names` values in a list. Hope that helps! ;) You only have to change your map data type with `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the basic format and content style of the main string then you can utilize a custom substring retrieval method to acquire the desired data. The method I provide below allows you to retrieve a substring contained between two other substrings, for example:

If you want to retrieve the file name related to the substring "filename=" (which of course is "mozilla.pdf") then you would supply the method with with a Left-String of `"filename=\""` and a Right-String of `"\""`.

The method returns a single dimensional String array of any occurrences where there may be a substring between the supplied Left and Right substrings so for the example above we would call the method like this:

```
String inputString = "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"mozilla.pdf\" "
                   + "Content-Description: mozilla.pdf Content-Disposition: attachment; "
                   + "filename=\"mozilla.pdf\"; size=92442; creation-date=\""
                   + "Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT\"; modification-date=\""
                   + "Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT\"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";

String[] fileNames = getSubstring(inputString,"filename=\"", "\"");

for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("File Name " + (i+1) + ":\t" + fileNames[i]);
}
```

This ultimately prints all file names found within the main input string to the console window. If you only want the first instance of a filename then you can place an index value at the end of the method call to retrieve the desired file name, for example:

```
String fileName = getSubstring(inputString,"filename=\"", "\"")[0];
System.out.println("File Name:\t" + fileName);
```

This will print: `File Name:     mozilla.pdf` to the console window.

Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves any string data located between the supplied string leftString
 * parameter and the supplied string rightString parameter.<br><br>
 * 
 * It can also retrieve a substring located at the beginning or the end of 
 * the main input string (see: leftString and rightString parameter information).
 * 
 * <p>
 * This method will return all instances of a substring located between the
 * supplied Left String and the supplied Right String which may be found
 * within the supplied Input String.<br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string to look for substring(s) in.
 *
 * @param leftString  (String) What may be to the Left side of the substring
 *                    we want within the main input string. Sometimes the 
 *                    substring you want may be contained at the very beginning
 *                    of a string and therefore there is no Left-String available. 
 *                    In this case you would simply pass a Null String ("") to 
 *                    this parameter which basically informs the method of this 
 *                    fact. Null can not be supplied and will ultimately generate
 *                    a NullPointerException. If a Null String ("") is supplied
 *                    then the rightString parameter <b>must</b> contain a String.
 *
 * @param rightString (String) What may be to the Right side of the
 *                    substring we want within the main input string. 
 *                    Sometimes the substring you want may be contained
 *                    at the very end of a string and therefore there is
 *                    no Right-String available. In this case you would 
 *                    simply pass a Null String ("") to this parameter
 *                    which basically informs the method of this fact.
 *                    Null can not be supplied and will ultimately generate
 *                    a NullPointerException. If a Null String ("") is supplied
 *                    then the leftString parameter <b>must</b> contain a String.
 * 
 * @param options     (Optional - Boolean - 2 Parameters):<pre>
 *
 *      ignoreLetterCase    - Default is false. This option works against the
 *                            string supplied within the leftString parameter
 *                            and the string supplied within the rightString
 *                            parameter. If set to true then letter case is
 *                            ignored when searching for strings supplied in
 *                            these two parameters. If left at default false
 *                            then letter case is not ignored. 
 *
 *      trimFound           - Default is true. By default this method will trim
 *                            off leading and trailing white-spaces from found
 *                            sub-string items. General sentences which obviously
 *                            contain spaces will almost always give you a white-
 *                            space within an extracted sub-string. By setting
 *                            this parameter to false, leading and trailing white-
 *                            spaces are not trimmed off before they are placed
 *                            into the returned Array.</pre>
 *
 * @return (1D String Array) Returns a Single Dimensional String Array
 *         containing all the sub-strings found within the supplied Input
 *         String which are between the supplied Left String and supplied
 *         Right String. Returns Null if nothing is found.
 * 
 *         You can shorten this method up a little by returning a List&lt;String&gt; 
 *         ArrayList and removing the 'List to 1D Array' conversion code at 
 *         the end of this method. This method initially stores its findings 
 *         within a List Interface object anyways.
 */
public static String[] getSubstring(String inputString, String leftString, String rightString, boolean... options) {
    // Return nothing if nothing was supplied.
    if (inputString.equals("") || (leftString.equals("") && rightString.equals(""))) {
        return null;
    }

    // Prepare optional parameters if any supplied.
    // If none supplied then use Defaults...
    boolean ignoreCase = false; // Default.
    boolean trimFound = true;   // Default.
    if (options.length > 0) {
        if (options.length >= 1) {
            ignoreCase = options[0];
        }
        if (options.length >= 2) {
            trimFound = options[1];
        }
    }

    // Remove any ASCII control characters from the
    // supplied string (if they exist).
    String modString = inputString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");

    // Establish a List String Array Object to hold
    // our found substrings between the supplied Left
    // String and supplied Right String.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Use Pattern Matching to locate our possible
    // substrings within the supplied Input String.
    String regEx = Pattern.quote(leftString) + 
                   (!rightString.equals("") ? "(.*?)" : "(.*)?") + 
                   Pattern.quote(rightString);
    if (ignoreCase) {
        regEx = "(?i)" + regEx;
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(modString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Add the found substrings into the List.
        String found = matcher.group(1);
        if (trimFound) {
            found = found.trim();
        }
        list.add(found);
    }

    String[] res;
    // Convert the ArrayList to a 1D String Array.
    // If the List contains something then convert
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        res = new String[list.size()];
        res = list.toArray(res);
    } // Otherwise return Null.
    else {
        res = null;
    }
    // Return the String Array.
    return res;
}
```

To retrieve the data contained within your supplied String:

```
System.out.println("Content-Type:\t\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"Content-Type:", ";")[0]);
System.out.println("Name:\t\t\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"name=\"", "\"")[0]);
System.out.println("Content-Description:\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"Content-Description:", "Content-Disposition:")[0]);
System.out.println("Content-Disposition:\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"Content-Disposition:", ";")[0]);
System.out.println("File Name:\t\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"filename=\"", "\"")[0]);
System.out.println("File Size:\t\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"size=", ";")[0]);
System.out.println("Creation Date:\t\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"creation-date=\"", "\";")[0]);
System.out.println("Modification Date:\t\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"modification-date=\"", "\"")[0]);
System.out.println("Content Transfer Encoding\t" + getSubstring(inputString,"Content-Transfer-Encoding:", "")[0]);
```

The output to console would be:

```
Content-Type:               application/pdf
Name:                       mozilla.pdf
Content-Description:        mozilla.pdf
Content-Disposition:        attachment
File Name:                  mozilla.pdf
File Size:                  92442
Creation Date:              Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT
Modification Date:          Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:14:00 GMT
Content Transfer Encoding   base64
```